# How Result using cross apply, can achieve using any other joins like inner,left,right join in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my SQL script with sample data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [VARCHAR](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LoginEntry]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LoginTime] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [EmpID] [INT] NULL,
    [GateNumber] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE Employee 
    ADD CONSTRAINT Pk_Employee PRIMARY KEY (Id)
GO

ALTER TABLE LoginEntry 
    ADD CONSTRAINT Fk_LoginEntry_Employee 
        FOREIGN KEY (EmpId) REFERENCES Employee(Id)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([ID], [Name]) 
VALUES (1, N'Employee 1'), (2, N'Employee 2'), (3, N'Employee 3'),
       (4, N'Employee 4'), (5, N'Employee 5'), (6, N'Employee 6')
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Employee] OFF
GO


SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[LoginEntry] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[LoginEntry] ([ID], [LoginTime], [EmpID], [GateNumber]) 
VALUES (1, CAST(N'2014-10-24 08:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, N'Gate 1'),
       (2, CAST(N'2014-10-24 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, N'Gate 1'),
       (3, CAST(N'2014-10-24 10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, N'Gate 2'),
       (4, CAST(N'2014-10-24 08:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2, N'Gate 1'),
       (5, CAST(N'2014-10-24 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2, N'Gate 1'),
       (6, CAST(N'2014-10-24 10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2, N'Gate 2'),
       (7, CAST(N'2014-10-24 08:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3, N'Gate 1'),
       (8, CAST(N'2014-10-24 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3, N'Gate 1'),
       (9, CAST(N'2014-10-24 10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3, N'Gate 2'),
       (10, CAST(N'2014-10-24 08:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4, N'Gate 1'),
       (11, CAST(N'2014-10-24 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4, N'Gate 1'),
       (19, CAST(N'2014-10-24 08:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5, N'Gate 1'),
       (20, CAST(N'2014-10-24 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5, N'Gate 1'),
       (21, CAST(N'2014-10-24 10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5, N'Gate 2'),
       (22, CAST(N'2014-10-24 08:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6, N'Gate 1'),
       (23, CAST(N'2014-10-24 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6, N'Gate 1'),
       (24, CAST(N'2014-10-24 10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6, N'Gate 2')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[LoginEntry] OFF
GO


SELECT 
    e.ID, dt.EmpId, Name, LoginTime
FROM 
    Employee e
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP 1
         l.ID, l.LoginTime, l.EmpId
     FROM 
         LoginEntry l 
     WHERE 
         l.EmpId = e.id) dt
GO
```

The result I get:

```
ID  EmpId   Name            LoginTime
-----------------------------------------------
1   1       Employee 1  2014-10-24 08:00:00.000
2   2       Employee 2  2014-10-24 08:00:00.000
3   3       Employee 3  2014-10-24 08:00:00.000
4   4       Employee 4  2014-10-24 08:00:00.000
5   5       Employee 5  2014-10-24 08:00:00.000
6   6       Employee 6  2014-10-24 08:00:00.000
```

I am Expecting the same result using Joins(inner,right,left,full) in sql server i tried my luck but couldn't, pls can any one help me out thanks in advance

Comment: Seriously, this is a good way to ask question. you only missed the 'order by' in the cross join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your query is incomplete.  When you use `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` you never have a guarantee *which one* it will pick.  New data, concurrent processes, re-indexing, software patches, the time of day, they all can cause the result to change.

So, it should be something like...

```
SELECT
  e.ID,dt.EmpId,Name,LoginTime
FROM
  Employee e
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1
    l.ID
   ,l.LoginTime
   ,l.EmpId
  FROM
    LoginEntry l
  WHERE
    l.EmpId=e.id
  ORDER BY
    l.LoginTime DESC   -- Will cause TOP 1 to pick the most recent value (per employee)
)
  dt
```

As for doing it with joins, doing the `TOP 1` *(or `greatest-n-per-group`, for which your `n` is `1`)*, is longer, messier, and slower.  So I won't go in to that.

But you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to do the `TOP 1` part, and then use a `JOIN` to associate that result with your main table...

```
WITH
  ordered_logins AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY LoginTime DESC, ID DESC) AS row_ordinal
  FROM
    LoginEntry
)
SELECT
  e.ID, l.EmpId, e.Name, l.LoginTime
FROM
  Employee e
LEFT JOIN
  ordered_logins l
    ON  l.EmpID = e.ID
    AND l.row_oridnal = 1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` assigns every row a value from 1 upwards *(per `EmpID` - the partition clause)*.  It's order by loginTime descending, so the latest logins are first, and just in case two logins have the exact same time, it's secondarily ordered by ID desc.

Then the `LEFT JOIN` only picks the rows numbered `1` *(the latest logins)* and if there are no logins gives `NULL`s instead *(so that the employee record is Not discarded due to a lack of join)*.

*Note: the `LEFT JOIN` equivalent for `APPLY` is to use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY`.*

Comment: not sure on efficiency, a quick test revealed that the row_number approach yielded the best performance, however an index on {employeeid, LoginTime} made the original query (plus the order by addition) faster.

Comment: @cato It really depends on the size of the table, the fragmentation of the indexes, etc.  Also, making the index `EmpID, LoginTime, ID` would help the second query, so that there would be no need to join back to the underlying table to get the ID value for the `ORDER BY`.  Really, I should have added `ID` to the `ORDER BY` in the first query too, but it didn't occur to me until I started on the second query.  *(Out of interest, how large and randomise was your test?)*

Comment: I had very little data, just the data provided - doesn't row_number risk calculating a huge number of orderings that are not needed?  We only need row_number 1, which is TOP 1, but we might be telling the query to sort 1000 records into order, then hand us #1.  Or on the otherhand query optimisation might be really clever and be able to spot not doing that.

Comment: @cato - The same concern applies to using `TOP` and `ORDER BY`.  How does it know which item is first if it's only ordered half of them, surely it needs to see all of them to know which is top?  The answer is that the optimiser uses indexes, and predicate-push-down to know when it can stop bothering anymore.  The concerns, consequences and internal optimisations are the same in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of showing one more way to solve the problem, the "longer, messier, and slower" `JOIN` method that (I thought) MatBailie didn't show would look like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  e.ID
 ,l.EmpID
 ,e.Name
 ,l.LoginTime
FROM
  dbo.Employee AS e
  JOIN
  dbo.LoginEntry AS l
    ON 
      l.EmpID = e.ID
ORDER BY 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.ID ORDER BY l.LoginTime DESC, ID DESC)
```

The `ROW_NUMBER` in the `ORDER BY` clause takes all of the logins for each Employee ID and numbers them by LoginTime with the most recent first (and using the LoginEntry ID as tie breaker, and thanks for that touch, Mat).

Then, the `SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES` does its thing. The `WITH TIES` bit means that it selects the number one result *from each `PARTITION BY` group* in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: The longer and messier one that I didn't show is `e JOIN l JOIN (SELECT emp, MAX(time) FROM l)`. But, I didn't realise SQL Server supported `ROW_NUMBER()` in the `ORDER BY`, I'll have to try to remember that.  Much tidier :)

Comment: I started before analytic functions were commonly supported, and have had to use MySQL.

Comment: I started out using Access97, so there's some (I know now) kludgy code in my past, too. But we work with the tools we have, right?

Answer (score 2):

you can use window function `row_number()`

```
    with cte as(    
SELECT e.ID,l.EmpId,Name,l.LoginTime, row_number() over(partition by e.ID order by l.LoginTime) as rn
FROM Employee e join LoginEntry l  on l.EmpId=e.id
    ) select ID,EmpId,Name,LoginTime from cte where rn=1
```

[demo link](https://rextester.com/EBYV56022)

Comment: Thank You Very much